# Loggin orders in firebase (Android application)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have created a resturaunt app for android in Android studio. I am using firebase to store the data. Each month i will bill the resturaunt 1 dollar per order made via the app. So i need some way to register each order and sort it by month. This has me kinda stumped so i don't want to release yet. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

What i would like is to have a table "Orders" with the 12 months. And i want to store a variable "amount" for each month. Like in the image below here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZtwb.jpg

whenever an order is submitted i want to get the value of "amount" for the specific month and then increase it by 1. This was the only way i could think of, i am sure there would be better ways and i am very open to suggestions.

Comment: Please be specific

Comment: @Zuhrain Yeah sorry, i should have clarified. I have edited my question, is it better now?